# Flow - intersection with union types error: "Property cannot be accessed on any member of intersection type"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Code can be tried [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIbAJZwHZQLxQN4BQUUANiqsAK4AmEAXFBpQLYBGEATgDRGmYDmFGvUYt2HAgF8oAMigAKQsRKJymACrgRAcgRxKGYBxDaexPQaMgGAZyOoM-KVAA++XiuRoNWhtrsoEKa8AcD0dhwOTpIAlAQEehh2UDZwzBDwXugYDJlqWLhKpORUtAwATAAMZnyOQmVQVTWe+ZqQfhaGxsHm+l3WUNoAqgDKAILaUvGJyfwQwHneGABqSCSU0LjyLUu5qksxtvaOOAB87sSoAGYKO9kAdHc+kDjYuLp9VtpxxMQc85QOFgnhh7p0rLwICQbBBeH8AUC+FlMPdQrDJEA)

I have a type that is an intersection of union types:

```
type Location = {
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
} & ({
  locationType: 'country',
  country: string
} | {
  locationType: 'state',
  state:string
})
```

I have another function that does something based on one of the union types:

```
const getLocationValue = (location: Location): string => {
  if (location.locationType === 'country')
    return location.country
  else
    return location.state
}
```

However, this gives me the error:

> property `country`. Property cannot be accessed on any member of intersection type

^ property `state`. Property cannot be accessed on any member of intersection type

Flow should be able to understand that if locationType is country, then it should have a country property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) Flow needs 2+ types between which to choose. Currently you have defined only a single type: `Location`. You can split the common values into a sort of "abstract" type and make `Location` a true type union in order to enable Flow to choose between them. It could look like the following:

```
type AbstractLocation = {
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
}

type CountryLocation = AbstractLocation & {
  country: string,
  locationType: 'country',
}

type StateLocation = AbstractLocation & {
  locationType: 'state',
  state: string,
}

type Location = CountryLocation | StateLocation
```

Try it: [working example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggRgZ2AJwIYGNgBkD27XACWOAdlALxQDeAUFFADYGHACuAJhAFxQmsC2cCMgA0dRqQDmLDt14ChomgF8aNUJCgBhHKxIoQufEVIVYiFBmx5mpgGTVx6XfuQgeSZIRKSx9BjYmJAAq4HIA5M56BuFiquphUADKwAQQRrZklPCeVhlBUA60-oHEIWE84UhpseLVwHKe3r4qahrQ+WVmOtFunaYAPsmpDf0kas4kSFAIOPzppaQ8Pa6Gi1mO-sxsnDwATAAMfhI+MrtQh8cBxmWhkJVRq7X0jwaVAKpJMOGtNJPTkgg1hupAAaqgGKxoJQABTXTI8MYASg8KGaFAAfJsoIQAGZQOHrAB08KCd2h5EokRcMSR4noyCBrGQZFJZSJrzc4ggDAQEHpUEZbBZEhBJCJ9X5yiAA) on flow.org