# Flow Type Check: How to iterate on possibly undefined property in redux action?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I have a Redux reducer for preferences and I am using Flow Type Checker. My reducer can take two types of actions. One for loading in all of the preferences which happens at initial app load. The second action type happens when the user updates a specific preference. Here is the code for my reducer. Where I run into problems is when I try to do `action.prefs.forEach` at which point flow throws an error saying `...'prefs': Property not found in 'object type'`

```
// @flow
import {
  UPDATE_PREF,
  LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/prefs';

export type actionType = {
  +type: string,
  prefs: Array<{_id: string, value: any}>
} | {
  +type: string,
  id: string,
  value: any
};

export default (state: stateType = {}, action: actionType) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS: {
      const newState = {};
      action.prefs.forEach(p => {
        newState[p._id] = p.value;
      });
      return newState;
    }
    case UPDATE_PREF: {
      return { ...state, [action.id]: action.value };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As you can see I have two types of actions. When loading all of the preferences, the action has an array of preferences. `[ { _id: 'color', value: 'blue' } ]` And when updating a single preference, I get an id and a value. So give my two action types that have different properties, how do I get flow to not throw errors about this variation in action flow types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some guidance from @ross-allen and some playing around on flow.org I have found a [working solution](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQPICCAIgPoAKASgKIBiAyqfQKoDCr199oAvKAOQESFGgyZsOXfgG4U6bKGblihACrURdXgKUr1m2jMSIsATwAOAU1ABDVRet8A3olCgA1GasAuUNgBOAJZoAOaIAL6yiJYAHuaw-jhe1jbIWIHo9lbaLm6eDr7JsJB4RGRUdIws7Jz0ADSuoOb+lpAYvoT+-jamADxOpIEAJr4BwSF1oABuNtAArpa+Nmim4QB8EaAAPqC5HsmFDsWKymoaFbQNbsOjWEGhV9OzC0srEVGx8YmgQ602c9AcAAKbA2LCLXbhHLhSapdLoJZpDJoLKWACUvDWu0agRKQLhyIAdMleDw+EJyqIqhJahi9m4CehCc1WhhCZAEtRUgALIHmTHYtxC0CoTCwaCWQlwEJ8tGyYXhOWNcKNDDwQJYZDc0D4pFM5J0xpuZA2DDWCkGak1Li+elC0UKNCWeD0LBgxyQ+XC2x6tDMlptdmcnl8gV24VOl1u8EAbXMhMGQwAutp4zN5pYvQqld7QC0sHN-GhQJHXe6s6AVcKTWaTnpzqJbUahfnC8WnKBCV3QeDJjHGX7hknEfC-emFpWK1Whb9IP9Ad5m25W0W-NHM8r3kA).

The short of it is that in addition to Ross' answer of adding `+type: UPDATE_PREF`, I also needed add `typeof`. So the working actionType is:

```
export type actionType = {
  +type: typeof LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS,
  prefs: Array<{_id: string, value: any}>
} | {
  +type: typeof UPDATE_PREF,
  id: string,
  value: any
};
```

Thanks again @ross-allen.

Answer (score 1):

In order to tell Flow which type to choose in the [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions), `+type` must be a value instead of `string`. Change your `actionType` to use values:

```
// @flow
import {
  UPDATE_PREF,
  LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/prefs';

export type actionType = {
  +type: LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS, // not just `string`
  prefs: Array<{_id: string, value: any}>
} | {
  +type: UPDATE_PREF,        // not just `string`
  id: string,
  value: any
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ross. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to get rid of the error.

Comment: @yourfavorite In addition to the above change, try my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640430/368697

Comment: I couldn't figure out what part of your example would solve the issue but I figured out how to fix the error on flow.org/try thanks to your example on there. I've created a flow with no errors, but now the problem is when an action for another part of the state gets fired, it causes a TypeError because it doesn't match either of my two actionTypes. I will create a new SO Question for this since it is kind of a different problem. And I'm creating a new answer with the solution in hopes it helps others in the future. Thanks for your help!